# Export SQL table with custom CASE columns included

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of data that has custom case columns added in to it from a query.

I'd like to export the data and include the custom case columns as part of it so that when I open it in excel it has the custom case columns and their data included.

Can't seem to find an answer anywhere on this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please create view of that table and add custom case columns then download report you get custom case columns.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Dinesh, this was exactly what I was looking for :)